# Does the Queen James Bible twist the original language the Scriptures were written in?

Tags: exegesis, bible-translation, kjv

The QJV, a pro - homosexuality translation based off of the KJV, published in 2012 by an anonymous group of editors, removes all "homophobic" references, claiming that the first homophobic reference was in 1946 - furthermore, claiming that "most scholars" agree with them. What does the original language say? Do they have any footing at all?

Info: https://www.gotquestions.org/Queen-James-Bible.html

Comment: It seems they wish to correct the wording of prophets and apostles and the words of Jesus of Nazareth himself. The written word is what it is. One either  accepts what is written - or one rejects it all, by being a critic of it and therefore imposing oneself above it.

Comment: A link would be helpful to substantiate the detail above. And a quotation from the pages might be a useful example to demonstrate what alterations are being suggested.

Comment: I've been unable to find an online version on the QJV, and I've only had access to it once. However, I do have a link to an article about it.

Comment: @NigelJ, I don't know about the QJV specifically, but Wikipedia seems to substantiate the claim (see my Answer)... in a sense at least.